# How to rewrite htaccess file so that it wont replace the root folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am writing the htaccess file but the problem is working in server but in local its rewriting the home folder:

When I am hitting the following URL :

> localhost:8080/rural/home/index

It automatically changing to :

> http://localhost:8080/home/index/

My root folder is getting removed! And in server as my all source code in root folder so its working fine!! How should I change the htaccess file locally so that it wont replace the root folder.

I am not sure what's I am missing here :

my .htaccess file is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Any suggestion will be a great help! Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file located, and what is your local vhost setup?

Comment: In the root folder. Under rural

Comment: I forgot to mention my vHost is setup in htdocs folder

Comment: "In the root folder. Under rural" - "In the root folder" is not the same as "under rural". If it's "under rural" then it's in the `/rural` subdirectory? If that is the case then that would seem to be the problem, as the `.htaccess` file is written as if it is in the "root folder" (ie. in the document root directory "htdocs"?), not "under rural". (?)